# Cannot import pywinauto on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywinauto

I installed `pywinauto` using `pip install pywinauto`.

OS: Windows 10

Python: 3.6.2

When I run `python` and try to import `pywinauto`, I get the error:

```
Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:57:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pywinauto.application import Application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pywinauto\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    from . import findwindows
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import controls
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from . import uiawrapper # register "uia" back-end (at the end of uiawrapper module)
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\uiawrapper.py", line 47, in <module>
    from ..uia_defines import IUIA
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pywinauto\uia_defines.py", line 181, in <module>
    pattern_ids = _build_pattern_ids_dic()
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pywinauto\uia_defines.py", line 169, in _build_pattern_ids_dic
    if hasattr(IUIA().ui_automation_client, cls_name):
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pywinauto\uia_defines.py", line 50, in __call__
    cls._instances[cls] = super(_Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pywinauto\uia_defines.py", line 60, in __init__
    self.UIA_dll = comtypes.client.GetModule('UIAutomationCore.dll')
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\comtypes\client\_generate.py", line 118, in GetModule
    mod = _CreateWrapper(tlib, pathname)
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\comtypes\client\_generate.py", line 183, in _CreateWrapper
    generate_module(tlib, ofi, pathname)
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\comtypes\tools\tlbparser.py", line 750, in generate_module
    gen.generate_code(list(items.values()), filename=pathname)
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\comtypes\tools\codegenerator.py", line 261, in generate_code
    tlib_mtime = os.stat(self.filename).st_mtime
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'UIAutomationCore.dll'
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I don't know if it helps in any way but it may be worth trying to download that `UIAutomationCore.dll` from the internet.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have the same issue today and fixed it by `pip install comtypes==1.1.7`.
It caused by **comtypes** library which release a new version 1.1.8 at Dec.26. Downgrade to previous version, it works well now.

Comment: Now it is fixed in `comtypes==1.1.9`. Please check.

Answer (score 4):

It should be fixed in comtypes==1.1.9. Please check.

The problem was introduced in `comtypes==1.1.8`. My fault.

Comment: Yes, windows `PATH` is hot mess. But the `import pywinauto` went from not working to working without my touching the `PATH` variable. Either one of those installs that I did modified my `PATH` to make it work, or there is something else going on.

Comment: Copying the .dll to my project folder seems to have worked.

Comment: You can check it in more details by examining os.environ[“PATH”] in Python.

Comment: The problem was in `comtypes`. I fixed it in `comtypes==1.1.9`. Please check.

Comment: Getting the same issue in comtypes==1.1.9 as well...retracted to 1.1.7 and it works well

Comment: The same problem persist in 1.1.12, Downgrading it to 1.1.9 worked for me. Thanks @VasilyRyabov for the heads up

Comment: @Dev how about `comtypes==1.1.11` ?

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Not tried that, I'll upgrade and let you know

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Yes `comtypes==1.1.11` works too, get's rid of this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different version of python (e.g. 3.7.5 or 3.8):

https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/887

"Had the same issue with Python 3.7.6 and 3.8.1. Issue does not occur in 3.7.5 or 3.8.
I think this will be fixed in 3.8.2 ( but not sure yet)"

Comment: So I installed a variety of Python versions and in each case I did `python3.x -m pip install pywinauto`. In each case the install completed successfully. After each install, I started the corresponding Python and tried `import pywinauto`. The versions I installed were 3.7.3, 3.7.9, 3.8.7, and 3.9.1 (in addition to the original 3.6.2).  In each case I got an error  as described in my original post. So I decided to post this comment, and started running `import pywinauto` again in each of those python versions. To my complete surprise, the original 3.6.2 now works!!! Mysteries of Windows!!!

Comment: Maybe it’s new release of comtypes. Try comtypes==1.1.7.

Comment: `comtypes==1.1.10` has more proper fix for both Win7 and Win10, just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, for me works fine

0. Install pywin32 from https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases
1. `pip install -U comtypes`
2. `pip install six`
3. `pip install Pillow`
4. `cd c:\windows\syswow64\`
5. `regsvr32 UIAutomationCore.dll`
6. `python`
7. `import pywinauto`
   #and the problem should be solved

I have Win10 and python 3.9..... i don't like Win10
Another thing could be your numpy library, uninstall it and install it again.
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy

Credits -> https://www.dll-files.com/download/65996a0afad353ec43ffe1ca69a2be88/uiautomationcore.dll.html?c=TTM2MGJJaHVRaEJkM1JyNDB3TDNwZz09

Comment: Installing Pillow seems to have done the trick for me on Windows 7.

Comment: It should be fixed in `comtypes==1.1.9` without any other tricks. Please check.